# loop in each cell array element in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I haven't used cell arrays in Matlab and have question.

I have 2 cell arrays `c` and `l`. I want `c` to have 10 matrices of dimension `10 x 785`. I want to loop through each row of the matrices in `c`.

For example, I want to replace each of these rows with another vector. How can I do it?

Here is the code that I currently have

```
k=10;
c={10};
l={10};
for v=1:10
  c{v}=rand(k,d);  
end
for a=1:10
    l{a}=zeros(k,1);
end
 for s=1 : 10
         for j=1:k
            l{s}=c{s,???}*xn';
         end
  end
```

in the final loop, I try to show which cell of `c` and `l`. But, how can I access each row of `c{1}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell reference can be used in any context where you'd use a full matrix.  So to get the j'th row of a matrix M, you'd do the normal `M(j,:)`.  To get the j'th row of a matrix stored in cell array `c`, you do `c{1}(j,:)`.

So in your case, `l{s}(j,:) = c{s}(j,:)*xn';`

Note that `c={10}` is not doing what you expect.  You can either say `c=cell(1,10)`, or you can clear c and let it build dynamically.

Finally, since each of the matrices are the same size, consider a 3d matrix instead of a cell array.  It will be perform better, and the syntax will be slightly more compact, and the particular operation you're doing will map to a matrix multiply:

```
l = zeros(k, 1, 10);
c = rand(k, d, 10);

% Refer to c(:, :, 1) to get the first matrix
```